# How do I copy a file chosen from a file dialog, then rename the copied file, all in one batch script?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, emulation, copy

I'm trying to semi-automate the setup of my Nintendo e-Reader .sav files (however, the file doesn't have to have a .sav file extension) using a batch script. The non-automated way I'd use would be to do the following in this order:

1. Find a file.
2. Copy the file to the same directory as *e-Reader (USA).gba* (my Nintendo e-Reader BIOS).
3. Rename the new copy of the file to *e-Reader (USA).sav* so it works with the program I choose to use the file with, which has the file name *visualboyadvance-m.exe*.
4. Load *e-Reader (USA).gba* in the program, along with the file, by dragging *e-Reader (USA).gba* to the program.

The semi-automated way would work by doing the following in this order:

1. Open the batch script.
2. Choose a file.
3. The script copies the file to the same directory as *e-Reader (USA).gba*.
4. The script renames the copy of the file to *e-Reader (USA).sav*. This new name for the file is fixed into the script.
5. The script opens *e-Reader (USA).gba*, along with the file.

These are two features I wish for my script to have:

1. It can be executed anywhere without being modified, whether the emulator is in a higher directory or a lower directory to the script. For example, a higher directory would be like C:\Script directory\Save directory, whereas a lower directory would be like C:\Save directory\Script directory.
2. The file can be in a different directory to the script, but must be in the same directory as *e-Reader (USA).gba*.

My code allows a file to be selected in a file dialog and opens *e-Reader (USA).gba* in the program, but can't even copy the file, instead giving me a *The system cannot find the path specified.* error. This is that code, which reproduces the issue with copying the file, and debugs the issue by saying the full path of the file that was selected, and also the current directory:

```
@echo off
set d="about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0)</script>"
for /f "tokens=*delims=" %%p in ('mshta.exe %d%')do set "f=%%p
echo Selected file: "%f%
echo Current directory: "%cd%
copy "%f%" "e-Reader (USA).sav
start "" visualboyadvance-m.exe "e-Reader (USA).gba"
pause
```

Comment: Delete the line `@echo off` and run for debug. If you can't see the error, post a screenshot of it.

Comment: The issue might simply be you need to use `copy "%f%" "e-Reader (USA).sav"` and be sure that contains the last double quote (**`"`**) since the destination file name contains a space. Otherwise maybe do a `CD /D "<dir>"` into the expected source directory of the files the copy command is copying so likely that equaling the value of the `"%f%"` variable. Be sure to check all your double quotes and use then and use ~ so for example `set "f=%%~p"` ... double check for missing quote and keep it consistent and not overlooked. Here's a link to example logic to test with https://pastebin.com/Tp3392HW

Comment: Now I've tried both suggestions. But my code still doesn't work. It uses the command `cd /d "%f%=~dp1"` to try to get the path of the file.